# How to add Breadcrumbs in views pages?

Tags: views

I have a page which list some products in a particular category and I have passed taxonamy term as contextual filter. Here is an example of my url: `www.example.com/prod_category`.

I want to show breadcrumb in my page like `home > prod_category` where `prod_category` is category of product. I have used [Custom Breadcrumbs](https://www.drupal.org/project/custom_breadcrumbs) module but couldn't find a solution.

Comment: did you try [custom breadcrumbs](https://www.drupal.org/project/custom_breadcrumbs) module it has nice integration with views.

Comment: If it's a page view, try the Path Breadcrumbs module

Answer (score 1):

You can create custom breadcrumb by adding this code :

```
<?php
global $base_url;
$breadcrumb[] = l('Home', null);
$breadcrumb[] .= l('Product Category', 'prod_category');
$breadcrumb[] .= l(drupal_get_title(), $base_url.$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
drupal_set_breadcrumb($breadcrumb);
?>
```

Refer to [LINK1](https://civicactions.com/blog/2010/mar/31/adding_custom_breadcrumbs_views_pages), [LINK2](https://techcommons.stanford.edu/topics/drupal-6x/breadcrumbs-views-pages) & [LINK3](http://www.leccionespracticas.com/informatica-web/drupal-informatica-web/drupal-7-path-breadcrumbs-in-views-page-solved)

Comment: I am not able to access prod_category field in views header. it is not shown in available variables. Is there a way to access that?

Comment: Have you check refer links

Comment: Ya i have checked but unfortunately it doesnt work. I will explain my doubt more clearly. In your suggested links its just printing a breadcrumb like         home>team etc. In my case i want my product category there instead of team. I cannot just give a particular category name there since categories changes according to url. for that i have to call my field for category type but unfortunately it cannot be done in views header. I have tried path breadcrumb also but cant get a solution.

Comment: Would you consider using views attachment to your view? And configure that using relationships used in your view to generate links needed, then wrap them up using a Global text field. I don't know if it suites you but I have managed to do that in the past and it should be semantically correct.

Comment: I used views attachment as you have mentioned and it works perfectly fine.